# How to use git for subsidiary sites?

Tags: git, version-control

I hope this is the right place to ask; smack me if not.

We have a website, currently maintained with git. We are in plans to resell the website, keeping the code and such on our server and rebranding it and making certain modifications for customers. It isn't a simple "show a different CSS", each customer will have actual code and logic modifications based off of our core code.

How best to manage this in git? I've looked at remotes, submodules, maintaining different repositories, but none seem to click.

My plan was, we have our core code repository, and every customer (including our own site) gets their own repo (or submodule, or what not). We can modify their specific code, and if we need to push something to the central code, it should then be easy to push that out to the customer sites as well.

I think my problem here is expressing what I want; if I could do that then git would probably answer with "here's what you need."

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you bulid a separate repo for their site/branding-specific code, and deploy your core code as a submodule?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why a simple branch wouldn't work in your case. If you have access control issues, you can always push these branches on different repositories (optionally on different machines), but based on what you describe I see no point in submodules or anything fancy.

Then, you can just merge your "core code" branch into each customer's branch when it hits a milestone.

Comment: branches is what you want

Answer (score 0):

In Git there's nothing special about the `master` branch other than that it's where you start. Most people use `master` as the "trunk" for all their branches, which I expect you would do with your core codebase.

The simplest way to handle your situation is with customer-specific `master` branches (e.g. `foo-company/master`, `bar-company/master`). You you don't have to use a branch "folder" per company, but it may help to keep anything company-specific separate from core dev. You *could* choose to use separate remotes instead, but I don't think the additional complexity would gain you anything *unless the customers need access to only their version of the code*.

As work is done in `master` and customers want new features, you have a few options:

1. Merge `master` into your `company/master` branches periodically, and resolve conflicts as they occur. Depending on the scope of the deviation from `master`, this may be challenging. `git rerere` may help.
2. If you always think of each customer's customization in terms of "changes since `master`", you may consider using `rebase` to keep up-to-date instead. If the changes are generally well-contained, this may make conflict resolution easier. Or you may end up hitting the same conflicts over and over again, if successive changes modify earlier ones.
3. If customers only want specific new features from `master`, you could use `cherry-pick` to pull the specific feature commits into company branches instead.